# How to select status variables into temp variables in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have selected global variables into temporary local variables like below.

```
mysql> select @@long_query_time into @a;  
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> select @a;  

+------+  
| @a   |  
+------+  
|    1 |  
+------+  
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

But when i am trying to do the same for status variables like below , i am getting error.

```
mysql> select @@qcache_hits;  
ERROR 1193 (HY000): Unknown system variable 'qcache_hits'
```

I know we can select status variables into temp variables using information_schema tables like below.

```
SELECT @a := variable_value from information_schema.global_status where variable_name='com_select';
```

But I want to know if there is any way to select server status variables into temp variables without using information_schema tables.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't think there is. You'll have to use information_schema.

Comment: You _could_ do `SHOW STATUS`, then parse the output.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [information_schema's table](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/status-table.html) for that purpose:

```
mysql> select VARIABLE_VALUE into @qcache_hits FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.GLOBAL_STATUS WHERE  VARIABLE_NAME="qcache_hits";
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> select @qcache_hits;
+--------------+
| @qcache_hits |
+--------------+
| 0            |
+--------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: yes i am aware of this. Please go through my question thoroughly. Anyway thanks Keriaki.

Answer (score 0):

From [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/using-system-variables.html):

> Some variables displayed by `SHOW VARIABLES` may not be available using `SELECT @@var_name` syntax; an *Unknown system variable* occurs. As a workaround in such cases, you can use `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'var_name'`.

Comment: The question is about **status** variables, the ones that are displayed by `show status like 'Qcache_hits'` to stick with the example from the question. It's not about the ones you can display with `show variables...`. With the latter you can configure the server on the fly, with the first one just the status of certain aspects are shown.